# TypeError: string indices must be integers..what is the problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i'm getting TypeError: string indices must be integers... how can i solve this?
And the code is:

```
def myfunc(x):
    y=''
    for i in x:
        y=y+x[i].upper() +x[i+1]
        i+=2

    return y
```

Comment: you should be careful about `x[i+1]`. You will probably receive `IndexError`. @nixon showed a right way about how you should implement `loop`.

Comment: I'd suspect it has something to do with ... `for i in 'nope': print(i)`.

Comment: `i += 2` doesn't have any affect, because the next iteration of the loop will simply overwrite the value of `i` with the next element of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You should index `x` iterating over the actual indices of `x`, not its values, thus doing `range(len(x))`, or `enumerate(x)`. Also you cannot modify the iterator in a `for` loop, you need a `while` if you want to do so:

```
def myfunc(x):
    y=''
    i = 0
    while i < len(x) - 1:
        y=y+x[i].upper() +x[i+1]
        i+=2

    return y
```

Comment: You will get an IndexError here if x is of odd length.

Comment: True @Moberg , was mainly focused in the logic of the loop and ignored the inner code. Should be ok now. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid iterating over indices when possible. You can do that there by iterating over `x` zipped with its own tail:

```
def myfunc(x):
    y = ''
    for x1, x2 in zip(x, x[1:]):
        y = y + x1.upper() + x2
    return y
```

Even better (and more efficient), you can use `join` to create `y` from one list.

```
import itertools
def myfunc(x):
    return ''.join(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x1.upper() + x2 for x1,x2 in zip(x, x[1:]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say: `for i in x:` is it like you are saying "*for each letter in the x string*", so at every iteration, `i` will be the next letter from the string. You can create a simple loop like you have with a `print i` statement to see the behavior.

Another problem with your code is the `x[i + 1]` statement. When the for loop will reach the last iteration, you'll try to access something non-existent and you'll get an `IndexError`. This being said, you should modify your code like this:

```
def myfunc(x):
    y = ''
    for i in range(0, len(x) - 1, 2):
        y = y + x[i].upper() + x[i + 1]
    return y
```

Because you want to iterate every other character, I also used another set of parameters for `range`: `range([start], stop[, step])`.

- start: Starting number of the sequence.
- stop: Generate numbers up to, but not including this number.
- step: Difference between each number in the sequence.

Cheers!

Comment: `i += 2` is meaningless; whatever change you make to `i` is overwritten by the next value in the thing you are iterating over.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that :) I updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry! I actually meant to add that comment to the question, and clicked on the wrong "add a comment" link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `enumerate`:

Code:

```
x = 'abcdef'

def myfunc(x):
    y = ''
    c = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(x):
        if i == c:
            y += j.upper()
        else:
            y += j
            c += 2
    return(y)


assert myfunc(x) == 'AbCdEf'

print(myfunc(x))
```

Output:

```
AbCdEf
```